# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { " using Reactify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, browserify, fixed-data-table

I am following a tutorial to create a [FixedDataTable with React](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/getting-started.html). However, I have some issues getting the following line to work in my jsx-file:

```
const {Table, Column, Cell} = require('fixed-data-table');
```

which gives the error (in Chrome):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I am using **browserify** and **reactify** to transform my jsx code to javascript. Other lines using require work fine.

I am quite new to JavaScript and React and would appreciate any suggestions to solve hte problem.

Comment: Are you using babel to transform this es6 syntax?

Comment: @NaisheelVerdhan No, I'm using a Browserify transform with "Reactify".

Comment: And you're actually opening that *transformed* Javascript in Chrome...? What's the actual Javascript that Chrome gets to see and that it chokes on?

Comment: @deceze Yes. It looks the same: const {Table} = require('fixed-data-table'); However, I have a debugger attached and the error references the untransformed javascript. Sorry if I'm being unclear.

Comment: I am not sure if Reactify transforms all es6 syntaxes. According to the docs, it does not. Just to check, have you activated the es6 option in browserify by `[ reactify --es6 ]`. Consider using babel to transform all es6 syntaxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was as pointed out in the comments that the ES6 option in reactify wasn't activated. I edited the following row in my gulpfile:

```
transform: [
    [ 'reactify', {'es6': true} ]
],
```

And then it worked. As a workaround I found out that you also can do:

```
var FixedDataTable = require('fixed-data-table');

var Table = FixedDataTable.Table;

var Column = FixedDataTable.Column;
```

instead of

```
var {Table, Column, Cell} = require('fixed-data-table');
```